# Valuations, Isomorphism, Local ring

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}, \, x \neq 0$, such that $x=p^r \frac{a}{b}, \quad a,b, r \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad p \nmid a, \quad p\nmid b$.
Let $v_p(x):=r$ and $v_p(0):= \infty$. Also, 
$$\mathcal O_p= \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : v_p(x) \geq 0\right\}= \left\{\frac{a}{b} : p \nmid b\right\} \quad \& \quad m_p= \left\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : v_p(x) > 0\right\}=\left\{\frac{a}{b} : p \nmid b \, \wedge p \mid a \right\}  $$
Show that $O_p / m_p \cong \mathbb{Z}/ p \mathbb{Z}$.

I have this:

$$\phi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow{} O_p \rightarrow O_p/m_p \;,\;\; s. t.\;\;a \mapsto \frac{a}{b} \mapsto \frac{a}{b} + m_p$$

I know that, $Ker(\phi)=p \mathbb{Z}$, but my problem is prove that $\phi $ is onto.

Any help is appreciated,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map, at least how I am seeing it, isn't well-defined. What is the $b$?

You should try mapping the other way:

Hint: Define

$$\phi:\mathcal{O}_p\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}:\frac{a}{b}\mapsto ab^{-1}+p\mathbb{Z}$$

This is well-defined, since $b$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Either direction is fine I think, OP should want $a\mapsto a\mapsto a+{\frak m}$ for his/her map (without $b$).

Comment: @anon That is true--I think this direction is more natural, since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_p$ ,so that $\mathcal{O}_p$ should project onto it.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks!

Comment: @P.M.O. If you are happy with an answer, you can click the little check-mark next to the users name to "accept" it. This is nice, because not only does it tell the user that you approve of their answer, it tells others that the problem is solved, that there isn't an immediate need for anyone to attempt to add more. If you could accept some of the answers given to you in the past few days that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Let $[x]\in{\cal O}/{\frak m}$ be an arbitrary equivalence class with representative $x=a/b\in{\cal O}\subset\bf Q$.

Then $p\nmid b\implies v(a)=v(a/b)\implies [a]=[a/b]=[x]$ with $a\in\bf Z$.

Comment: If you want to attack it with his map (I guess he needs to verify that it is well-defined?) then wouldn't be easier to just note that the two quotients have the same <b>prime</b> order.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Verifying it has the same prime order seems exactly as hard (easy) as verifying ${\cal O}/{\frak m}\cong{\bf Z}/p{\bf Z}$ to me.